# TypeError: store.getState is not a function

Tags: reactjs, redux

I've been trying to implement redux-persist with my react redux project. Here's what I have.

store.js:

```
import {compose, createStore, applyMiddleware} from 'redux';
import {persistStore, autoRehydrate} from 'redux-persist';
import {combineReducers} from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';

import reducer from './reducers/reducer';
import modalReducer from './reducers/modal-reducer';

const store = createStore(
            combineReducers({
                reducer,
                modalReducer,
            }),
            compose(
                applyMiddleware(thunk),
                autoRehydrate()
            ), 
        )

export default persistStore(store);
```

index.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {Provider} from 'react-redux';
import {BrowserRouter} from 'react-router-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import store from './store';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';

ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <BrowserRouter>
            <App />
        </BrowserRouter>
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById('root'));
registerServiceWorker();
```

I do know that if I were to export default the just store, and not persistStore(store) in store.js, then the code works and I don't run into the error. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the reason why that is happening is because module.exports stores objects. When you call `export default persistStore(store);` you're trying to export the invocation, not the object. That is why `export default store;` works, and I believe what nathan hayfield wrote will work as well.